# Finding the ring of integers of a cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x)=x^3-9x-6$ with $a\in \mathbb{C}$ a root of $f(x)$. I need to show that the ring of integers of $L=\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is $O_L=\mathbb{Z}[a]$. I computed the discriminant of $f(x)$ to be 1944. Even by Stickelberger's theorem, I narrowed down $(O_L:\mathbb{Z}[a])$ to 1 or 3. I need to show it must be 1. Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Since $1944 = 2^3\cdot 3^5$, how did you show (with Stickelberger or another method) that $[\mathcal O_L:\mathbf Z[a]] \not= 9$?

Comment: I forgot about that possibility. Hence I didn't show it

Comment: Aha! In that case you should use the method suggested by André 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is Eisenstein at $p = 3$, we can apply the following result, Theorem 2.3 of Keith Conrad's [Totally Ramified Primes and Eisenstein Polynomials](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf).

**Theorem.** Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of an Eisenstein polynomial at $p$. Then $p \nmid [\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$.